# More interactive Grails app (like Sproutcore)

Tags: jquery, grails, css, sproutcore

There are some questions I have.

I'm currently writing webapps using [Grails](http://grails.org/). Now i played a bit with [Sproutcore](http://sproutcore.com/) and there are some advantages as the beautiful ui and the easy data binding with automatic ajax/javascript updates.

Is it possible to use *grails' domain and service logic from* Sproutcore (rather than only the database model for the backend) when I use Sproutcore with Grails?

Are there other "desktop feeling", userfriendly web frameworks outside that can be used with grails (or some other framework and language - as long as it pays back the effort)?
I know there is [Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org/), [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/), [ZK](http://www.zkoss.org/) and [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org). But all except cappuccino lacks the beautiful ui widgets. The rest seem to work good for intra-business projects, but not for beauty cloudapps.

Is it (without too much effort) possible to enhance Grails standard templates with CSS3/HTML5/jQuery to reach the same feeling as in Sproutcore apps (in principle it should be possible to build something like [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/))? Where is a good starting point? Are there opensource apps to look at? Or good tutorials?

Maybe it would have been best to separate this into smaller questions, but I think the fit together...

Thx in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good fit to the architecture you described is to expose your grails components as services.

Grails has fairly good REST support to bind scaffolded controller actions to REST services,

```
static mappings = {
   "/product/$id?"(resource:"product")
}
```

You might have to edit the templates used, but it's probably easier to change them to output JSON or SOAP responses and use the support for this with your favorite ajax-friendly framework.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#REST

I imagine there are a few more considerations to a cloud friendly architecture, and would suggest spending a couple of hours watching these 2 screencast that expand on this type of architecture:

http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/home/change-grails

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axOPJbrIjkY

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANY javascript framework you want with Grails.  If you are using a RIA js framework, your Grails backend will still use Domain objects, Services, and Controllers; the only difference is you are going to be returning mostly json from your controllers.  You aren't going to be using too many GSPs.

> Is it possible to use domain logic and service logic via Sproutcore
>   (rather than only the database model for the backend) when I use
>   Sproutcore with Grails?

It's a bad idea.  The server needs to be the single point of truth for your app.  The business rules need to be enforced on the server.  Else someone could hack their client and get bad data into your app.

Comment: Well yes, thats what I meant. But I didnt write it correctly. I want to call grails domain logic directly from sproutcore to not give any other the chance read the code...And besides controller actions I didnt really know how to do that